# Create a library and then redefine a function in main , C

Tags: c, function, generics, hashmap, libraries

Can I create my own library and redefine a function in main.c? I mean , for example: I create a library with 4 functions in which one is called `Hash(void* parameter)` <- generic parameter. I need that ,the user, who implement my library, has to redefine in his main the function `Hash()` with his parameter. So I need just to initialize the function in my library and then the user has to implement it. Can I do this?

Comment: yes, you can declare the function and not define it

Comment: When you create a library,others will make use of it, they need not to define functions again, they will just call your functions.

Comment: Function overloading is not possible in C. By 'initialize the function in my library', do you mean you declare it, but the user has to define it? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Use function pointer. Let your lib function indirectly call the user function. The user could redirect the fnc pointer to his own implementation.

Comment: yes, I declare it in my library and the user has to implement it. He is obliged to implement it in his file. @ErdalKüçük

Comment: It depends if you need compile time redirection or runtime redirection. If the user who uses your lib gets a linker error he will probably be confused. He would probably not conclude that he needs to provide the function on his own. Using function pointers is more versatile.

Comment: pqans made a good point. Best, print a message that this function is not implemented yet, or gracefully exit.